# jquery validation with regular expression

Tags: regex, jquery-ui

I want to validate a field which will allow only "xxxx"[not " " or "xxxx"" or somthing else] with regular expression in Jquery validator ,so what the regular expression would be...plzz suggest.

Answer (score 0):

A general regex you should match would be -

```
^"[x]+"$
```

(I assume you only want character 'x' as you defined in question and x does not mean 'any character' )

**Edit:**
As per your comment here is the modified regex you should be using -

```
^"[^"]+"$
```

Comment: no  by "X" i want to mean any character.the reg ex should be like that so that i can search any general string like ABCD & "ABCD" not something else.in the qoute i can provide any no of characters as well.then wht to do??

Comment: i guess this is not working..earlier i was using  /^[a-z0-9_ *-]+$/ this regex,now i just want to add the validation i have already mentioned.wat to do?

Comment: This is not different than your earlier regex except for addition of quotes. I am not sure why this is not working in your case probably it may require some escaping of quote by prefixing it with '\'.